# Get Chrome snippet to run each time page refreshes

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

I'm trying to test a piece of javascript on a page that checks whether to see if text on a page changes. If it does, it sends an alert.

I can run the snippet and it works once, but then the page refreshes (as commanded by the code), and then presumably the snippet is no longer running?

Is there a way for me to get this snippet to automatically run every 60 seconds when the page reloads?

Thanks

Comment: No. Use any extension that allows running custom user code.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working using this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/run-javascript/lmilalhkkdhfieeienjbiicclobibjao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/run-javascript/lmilalhkkdhfieeienjbiicclobibjao